# Excel multi layer if vlookup and formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I've produced a simplified document that shows the essence of what I'm trying to achieve.

Please see the picture for the image of the document.
[image: Picture]

There are 5 shops that all stock Apples, Pears, Bananas, and Oranges.

Internally, stock is moved and bought very regularly. Hence the 'Stock Location and Amount' Section. Below is the 'September Stock Movement' - which shows where the stock has moved to and from. There is also an option if more stock is bought or sold - from the bank.

I need to create a formula that tracks the internal stock depending on the 'September Stock Movement' section - I've filled in some details to this section. If the formula in the 'Stock Location and Amount' section was complete then the data below would apply/work.

If it's a transfer of stock then it needs to reduce one shop's stock and add to the other. If it's a buy then it just needs to add it directly to the location of the shop receiving the purchase and reduce the balance in the bank, and if it's a sell it needs to reduce the shops stock but increase the bank's balance.

Note - the prices of the products are different.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What would be the expected result?

Comment: Several formulas - =IF(AND(B2=H2,$C$1=K2),VLOOKUP(B2,$H$2:$K$5,2,FALSE),"") - This was a formula from the actual worksheet - not the one of the picture above. I can move stock from one row i.e. shop1 receives 5 apples, but I can't reduce that amount from where the stock came from.

Comment: The goal is so that any changes fro the September stock movement is automatically adjusting the stock location and amount section

Comment: Depending on whether its a buy/sell/transfer

Comment: I've literally been googling for hours and have no where else to go to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use SUMIFS to get totals. If a shop appears in the TO section, it **increases** its stock. But iif the shop appears in the FROM section, it **decreases** the total stock for that shop.